# Correct workflow of a REST API for mobile app authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, authorization, mobile-application

I am in the process of building a REST API for mobile app developers to be used on a web application built using Zend framework. My first task is to create a service for authentication/authorization. I have read lots of related questions here on SO and would like to sum up what I am doing:

1. There is no session or cookie involved, so a typical web app method
   of checking the logged in state of the user doesn't work here.
2. With each login request, the username and password is received and a
   random string is generated and saved in the DB against the username.
   Also, this string is returned with the authentication request.
3. This user token is sent along with any request that needs authentication.This token is matched against the stored value in DB and if matched, only then the user is allowed to perform the required task.
4. On logout, the token value in the DB is reset to blank or NULL.

Is this the correct approach ? Won't it over load the DB because with each request, a select query is run on the DB to check for the token value ? If you could provide any tutorial link, that'd be much appreciated.